# Jquery - How to make bind click event for multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Iam using jquery to animate an image to make a mixed up image that scrolls different parts when clicked.

I thought of doing  like this

```
$("#head").click(function () {
        if (headclix < 9) {
            $("#head").animate({
                left: "-=367px"
            }, 500);
            headclix++;
        } else {
            $("#head").animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 500);
            headclix = 0;
        }
    });

    $("#eyes").click(function () {
        if (eyeclix < 9) {
            $("#eyes").animate({
                left: "-=367px"
            }, 500);
            eyeclix++;
        } else {
            $("#eyes").animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 500);
            eyeclix = 0;
        }
    });

    $("#nose").click(function () {
        if (noseclix < 9) {
            $("#nose").animate({
                left: "-=367px"
            }, 500);
            noseclix++;
        } else {
            $("#nose").animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 500);
            noseclix = 0;
        }
    });

    $("#mouth").click(function () {
        if (mouthclix < 9) {
            $("#mouth").animate({
                left: "-=367px"
            }, 500);
            mouthclix++;
        } else {
            $("#mouth").animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 500);
            mouthclix = 0;
        }
    });
```

I hope there is better way of doing it

I'm thinking I can do something with the class and each but not sure how to quite make it work. need to make it a click event and keep track of each image part

```
$(".face").each(function (i) {
        if (i < 9) {
            $(".face").parent().animate({
                left: "-=367px"
            }, 500);
            i++;
        } else {
            $(".face").parent().animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 500);
            i = 0;
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pic_box">
                <div id="head" class="face"><img src="images/headsstrip.jpg"></div>
                <div id="eyes" class="face"><img src="images/eyesstrip.jpg"></div>
                <div id="nose" class="face"><img src="images/nosesstrip.jpg"></div>
                <div id="mouth" class="face"><img src="images/mouthsstrip.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```

[image in this link will give you an idea of the functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjz18.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: You can replace all the repeating blocks with only one of them that uses `$(".face").click(..)` and `$(this).animate(..)`.

Comment: You're on the right track with your final code example, but you still need two things: how to save and associate the number of clicks to each individual part of the face and how to register your generalized function as a click handler. For that, try `$('#head, #eyes, #nose, #mouth').on('click', function(i) { ...etc.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a face object that holds the click counts of each face part and also a function to handle the click event (named clickHandler below). The clickHandler takes in an `id` and calls the appropriate animate function on the element that has that `id`.

Check below:

```js
var face = {
  "headClicks" : 0,
  "eyesClicks" : 0,
  "noseClicks" : 0,
  "mouthClicks" : 0,
  "clickHandler" : function(id) {
    if(this[id+"Clicks"] < 9) {
      animateLeft367(id);
      this[id+"Clicks"]++;
    } else {
      animateLeft0(id);
      this[id+"Clicks"] = 0;
    }
  }
}

function animateLeft367(id) {
  $("#" + id).animate({left: "-=367px"}, 500);
  console.log('animated ' + id + ' 367');
}

function animateLeft0(id) {
  $("#" + id).animate({left: "0px"}, 500);
  console.log('animated ' + id + ' 0');
}


$(".face").click(function() {
  face.clickHandler(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pic_box">
    <div id="head" class="face"><img src="images/headsstrip.jpg"></div>
    <div id="eyes" class="face"><img src="images/eyesstrip.jpg"></div>
    <div id="nose" class="face"><img src="images/nosesstrip.jpg"></div>
    <div id="mouth" class="face"><img src="images/mouthsstrip.jpg"></div>
</div>
```